# Prestashop PDF Delivery Slip in Order History

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

It is possible to print/download the PDF Delivery Slip from Frontend, from Order History?

- Invoice is possible
- Order Return to
- Order Slip also

Why cannot download the PDF Delivery Slip if the Order state is **shipped**?
I found this controller:

```
PdfOrderSlipController
PdfOrderReturnController
PdfInvoiceController
```

I need something like

```
PdfDeliverySlipController
```

It is possible in PS or not?

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code:

**To Download Invoice Slip**

```
$order = new Order((int)$id_order);  
$order_invoice_list = $order->getInvoicesCollection();  
Hook::exec('actionPDFInvoiceRender', array('order_invoice_list' => $order_invoice_list));  
$pdf = new PDF($order_invoice_list, PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE, Context::getContext()->smarty);  
$pdf->render();  
exit;
```

**To Download Delivery Slip**

```
$order = new Order((int)$id_order);  
$order_invoice_collection = $order->getDeliverySlipsCollection();   
$pdf = new PDF($order_invoice_collection, PDF::TEMPLATE_DELIVERY_SLIP, Context::getContext()->smarty);  
$pdf->render();  
exit;
```

In admin panel, Once if you marked your order either as shipped or delivered, Prestashop generates a delivery number against the corresponding order and subsequently generates delivery slip for that delivery number. As delivery number generates only one time due to which you cannot generate multiple delivery slips for same delivery number.

Comment: i only want to download the generated PDF from the Front Office ( history.tpl ) now i generated a file with this code:                                     `public function display()
    {

        $order = Order::getByDelivery((int)Tools::getValue('id_delivery'));
        $order_invoice = new OrderInvoice((int)$id_order_invoice);
        $pdf = new PDF($order_invoice, PDF::TEMPLATE_DELIVERY_SLIP, Context::getContext()->smarty);  
        $pdf->render();  
    }`

Comment: but only brings 00000-1pdf., here also my history.tpl code

Comment: <a class="link-button" href="{$link->getPageLink('pdf-delivery-slip', true, NULL, "id_order={$order.order_invoice}")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Lieferschein'}" target="_blank">
         <i class="icon-file-text large"></i>{l s='Delivery Slip'}
        </a>

Comment: my controller calls PDFDeliverySlipController.php

Comment: You can create your own custom function in your front controller and redirect customer to that function on clicking button. In custom function, put the shared code. This code will generate and download delivery slip. For more specific, please share your code

Answer (score 1):

this is my PDFDeliverySlipController (controllers/front)

`class PdfDeliverySlipControllerCore extends FrontController`
`{`
`public $php_self = 'pdf-deliveryslip';`

```
protected $display_header = false;
protected $display_footer = false;

public function postProcess()
{
    if (!$this->context->customer->isLogged() && !Tools::getValue('secure_key')) {
        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication&back=order-history');
    }

    $id_order = (int)Tools::getValue('id_order');

    if (Validate::isUnsignedId($id_order)) {
        $order = Order::getByDelivery((int)Tools::getValue('id_delivery'));
    }

    if (!OrderState::invoiceAvailable($order->getCurrentState()) && !$order->invoice_number) {
        die(Tools::displayError('Lieferschein nicht verfügbar'));
    }

    $this->order = $order;
}
    public function display()
    {
        $order = Order::getByDelivery((int)Tools::getValue('id_delivery'));
$order_invoice_collection = $order->getInvoicesCollection();   
$pdf = new PDF($order_invoice_collection, PDF::TEMPLATE_DELIVERY_SLIP, Context::getContext()->smarty);  
$pdf->render();  
    }
}`
```

and this my link on the history.tpl

`<a class="link-button" href="{$link->getPageLink('pdf-deliveryslip', true, NULL, "id_order={$order.id_order}")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Lieferschein'}" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="icon-file-text large"></i>{l s='Delivery Slip'}
                                </a>`

Result: i only have blank Page without error (debug On)

Comment: In controller, you have get your order using "id_delivery" but in your link, you have passed only id_order. Also add the id_delivery in your link.